# $(selector) equivalent in Ext 3

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a menu component and I am trying to select the link selected by adding a class on click and removing the class from all menu items before adding it again to the newly clicked link.

So I simply find the parent component and query it to find all anchors.  Then I try to chx the classes of all the anchors and remove the one/ones that are the "selected" class.

```
var anchors = component.el.query("a");
Ext.iterate(anchors, function(anchor, i){
anchor.removeClass('selected');
});
this.el.addClass('selected');
```

Does not work.  Yet:

```
var anchors = component.el.query("a");
Ext.iterate(anchors, function(anchor, i){
$(anchor).removeClass('selected');
});
this.el.addClass('selected');
```

Does work.
What would be the Ext native equivalent to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ExtJS 3 your anchors[index] will return the HTML for that specific node. To use `addClass` or `removeClass` you will need to use anchors.item(index);

Something like this would work:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var div = Ext.get('test'),
        anchors = div.select("a"),
        linkChangeClass = function (anchors, anchor) {
            var index = anchors.indexOf(anchor);
            anchors.removeClass('selected');
            anchors.item(index).addClass('selected');
        };

    anchors.on('click', function() {
        linkChangeClass(anchors, this);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98c6a57e/